# react frontend for django without any rest api calls

Tags: django, reactjs

At the moment I have a django backend with jquery frontend. Looking to move to reactjs. The issue is that I don't have a server per se, so I can't make calls to django from frontend.

My website is not publicly available, but sent as a html document by email. So django is used just to crunch a lot of data and make a lot of plots and tables, then I use django-bakery to output all of that into a static html file that gets sent by email.

My question is how would you go from a standard django html template:

```
<div class="card">
  {% for k, v in tables.items %}
    <div id="{{ k }}">
```

To a reactjs template, without making calls to a django server. How would I get the data from django?

Thanks!

Comment: you can send the data from backend in a script tag assigning it to a global variable, which you can access in your react code.

Comment: @VishalSharma assigning it to the window variable and reading it in react?

Comment: yes, that would work. kind of like a "datastore"